# How to refer an entity that has name in a shortened way?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, names

For instance,

> The Games-X

vs

> The X-Games

In the first one, I would say that it could be a shortened way to say the ***"The Games named X"*** or the ***"The Games which name is X"***

But in the second one ***"X"*** is the adjective giving the quality ***"X"*** to the noun ***"Games"***

I’m asking this because some times, when writing stuff related to computer programming, I use both ways:

> The method Foo is an instance function of the class Bar

and

> The Foo method is an instance function of the Bar class

Which one is the correct way?

In the first sentence, ***"Foo"*** and ***"Bar"*** are the ones that are a ***"method"*** and a ***"class"*** respectively

In the second sentence, ***"method"*** and ***"class"*** are the ones which names are ***"Foo"*** and ***"Bar"***

Comment: Are you actually talking about the X games or are you just using X as a placeholder? If the latter is the case, you might want to use a different term. http://xgames.espn.go.com/

Comment: @Catija I'm using X games as an example, because X can be either an adjective or the name of the noun, like in X-rays

Comment: I feel like the first use example is more of an appositive without commas...

Comment: I think, in writing for programming purposes, your first example is perfectly acceptable and used often... but I'd guess the second is as well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762319/call-method-of-the-derived-class-through-reflection-possible-or-no

Answer (score 1):

*The method Foo* is acceptable in the context of programming. You can also add quotes: *The method "Foo"*.